# Unable to find in Play Store (Item Not Found)

Tags: support, status-completed, android-app

I am having a problem downloading the application on the play store, clicking the link just gets me to an "Item Not Found" page. I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 in case it matters.

**Steps to reproduce**

- Open the community page with Google+ app on my Android device
- Click the link
- Click the "Join Testing" (or whatever that button says)
- Click the download link
- Select to open in Google Play
- "Item not found" error

Comment: @gnat: That is not a duplicate. I had initially put my answer directly on that question (it is now deleted), but I created this question because I realized that it wasn't the same problem. Also, that question has "Status-Completed", so if it was the same issue I wouldn't have had the problem this morning. right?

Comment: I am having the same issue. It seems that it takes some time before play store knows that you are in the testing group

Comment: Where is this duplicate question?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: The problem has now been fixed, so the following work around is no longer applicable.

---

I managed to get around it as follows:

- Open the community page with Google+ app on my Android device
- Click the link
- Click the "Join Testing" (or whatever that button says)
- Click the download link
- Select to open in Chrome (web browser)
- Click the "Install" button
- Wait for package to download
- "Package not a valid format" error (yet another problem)
- Click "OK" (or something)
- It then automatically opens the correct Play Store page, where you can click Install and it will download and install correctly